# Sending JSON having dynamic values in POST body request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post

New to Javascript and had a basic query

For a POST AJAX request , I need to send following data in JSON format in the body parameter, however the longitude, latitude and radius values are dynamic, i.e. will be fed based on current location.

```
{
  "inGeoFence" : {
    "gpsCircle" : {
      "longitude": 122.2620,
      "latitude": 37.4996,
      "radius": 180000
    }
  }
}
```

The static way to write this is

```
 "data": "{\r\n  \"inGeoFence\" : {\r\n    \"gpsCircle\" : {\r\n      \"longitude\": 77.348235,\r\n      \"latitude\": 28.533938,\r\n      \"radius\": 100\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n"
```

Above  data works fine since all are static values and a string is formed.

Can you please suggest me to write the same JSON so that dynamic values can be fed. Also what is the best/proper way to send JSON?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse(your_json_var)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just construct JS object and that stringify it:

```
"data": JSON.stringify({
    inGeoFence: {
        gpsCircle: {
            longitude: getLong(),
            latitude: getLat(),
            radius: getRadius()
        }
    }
});
```

---

You can also send `data` as JS object and in server side read it as array:

```
$.ajax({
     data: {
      inGeoFence: {
        gpsCircle: {
          longitude: $('#long').val(),
          latitude: $('#lat').val(),
          radius: $('#radius').val()
        }
      }
    }
});

[server side, e.g. PHP]
$_POST['inGeoFence']['gpsCircle']['longitude']
```